# Importing multiple projects with the same name in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I have multiple projects with the same name in different directories.

How can I import them in the same workspace in Eclipse?

Comment: Why do you really want this? If the projects are related to eachother, they should probably have a different name. If not, put them into a different workspace.

Comment: "Why do you really want this?" Two words: Source control

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can change the `name` tag in the `.project` file in every project that you want to import before importing it

Comment: Great @Cesar it worked. This is my long year problem but solved now ;)

Comment: It gets reverted back to the original name after import

Answer (score 17):

There is an advance option available in eclipse and there you can provide the details asked and it should work...

Right Click >> Import >> "Select option Import Existing Maven Projects or from an archive file or directory" >> Advanced

[image]

Comment: I'm not using Maven in this project. But thanks for helping, I think it can be useful for other people.

Comment: For Maven projects, this is the best answer. No need to edit .project files. You can then group your projects into different Working sets.

Answer (score 5):

When you import existing projects (depending on your Eclipse version) you can give it a new name in the import window. Otherwise import it as normal and rename it by right clicking the project in your Package Explorer and going `Refactor > Rename`.

If you want to keep the original names then as Juned Ashan said, untick the `Copy Projects into Workspace` checkbox and the files will remain in their original locations and will not interfere with each other.

Comment: This did not work for me! I am still trying to figure out how!

Answer (score 5):

You can use advanced options and can add any prefix, suffix, or even eclipse suggests some templates like [groupId]:[artifactId]-[version]

[image]

Comment: This also works only with Maven projects.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of importing the project, begin creating a new project with a different name. Then change the location of the project to your new existing project. Eclipse will then let you create the project using the existing directory and content.

Comment: In my opinion this is the only answer that directly addresses the question.  When I did this I did get a new file, `.settings/org.eclipse.cdt.debug.core.prefs`, for some reason but it looks innocuous.  This did _not_ change the name entry in `.project`.  My use case is multiple copies of the same project checked out of a revision control system.  I will frequently do this when switching back and forth between working on different tasks on the same project.  Oh yeah, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try doing this:

Uncheck "copy projects into workspace" checkbox while importing the project with the same

Comment: Thanks for helping, but I have got the message: "_Some projects cannot be imported because they already exist in the workspace_".

Comment: @CássioMolin There is no way that you can have two projects with the same name in a workspace. But you can have the same name projects in two different workspaces.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to import a Maven project, you can use the *Advanced* option as [explained in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19731773/4850949). Unfortunately, this option is not available in other Import wizards. However, here's a **general solution that should always work**:

Do not import the project, but instead

1. create a new project using *Import > General > Project* (or whatever project type you want)
2. enter a (different) name and press *Finish*
3. right-click on the new project and select *Import > General > File System* (or *Archive File* if it is in an archive)

This will add the existing project files under the project's new name.

Answer (score -1):

If you have same names as Maven Project I assume that you will have the same classes or feature files too. In that case, you most likely will have some conflicts when you try to run your feature files or pull/push from a repository.

There is an easy way to solve the problem: delete the oldest version from the remote repository and from your working space, and make your project unique. If you still get the same problem even running your feature file as Cucumber I strongly recommend checking your reference points, as you may need to change them manually.